# How to change the name of wireless interface?

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek-wireless

I installed ubuntu 20.04 a few months ago and installed the appropriate driver for my wireless inbuilt adapter but when i run ifconfig or iwconfig, it shows the name as `wlp2s0`. It creates a problem for me as many of the scripts of wireless tools searches for `wlan0`

**So, I want to rename it to wlan0 for my convenience**

Here is the output of the command `iwconfig`

```
vboxnet0  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Redmi 6a"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: 22:A6:0C:72:92:FD   
          Bit Rate:87 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=65/100  Signal level=-74 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

and here is the output of `lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet|wireless|wi-fi'`

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Answer (score 3):

Hard-coded wireless device names in scripts? Well that's no fun. Fortunately, it's not too difficult to change the interface name.

1. Create a file as `root` named: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`
2. Add this:
   `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:01:02:03:04:05", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="wlan0"`
3. Reboot

Be sure to change `00:01:02:03:04:05` to the proper MAC address of your wireless device. This should give you what you need.